# Linux на Android

Tags: android, linux

Запустил Debian из-под Proot на Андроид, но существуют ли другие способы запуска Linux на Android?

Со временем хочу перевести весь аппарат на Linux, но пока запускаю через Termux.

Для начала хочу отвязаться от Termux, так как там всё жёстко завязано на определённые пути , в частности на папку /data/data/com.termux.

---

Итак, пока у меня такой план действий :

1. Запустить тот-же дистрибютив Debian или другую Linux-систему в
   простом терминале ...
2. Пересобрать Linux по книге
   "LinuxFromScratch" и примонтировать для запуска через TWRP.
3. Через TWRP запустить новую платформу , параллельно со старой и
   разработать приемлемый оконный интерфейс.
4. Полностью перейти на новую платформу.

- Какие подводные камни меня ждут и как их обойти?
- Есть ли альтернативные варианты перевода телефона на Linux?

Телефон имеет порядка 4 GB оперативки и 32 GB памяти , архитектура arm64 ( aarch64 , arm64-v8a). Пока не рутирован, но думаю Samsung рутировать не создаст больших хлопот.

Comment: "Какие подводные камни меня ждут и как их обойти?" - время. Это может занять очень очень много времени. Также, по ходу дела может выясниться, что нужно будет раздобыть/написать самому драйвера для разных устройств. Так в свое время для одного с нексусов не выпускали обновку, так как для свежего ядра не было видеодрайвера, а компания, которая его сделала то ли канула в лету, то ли ещё куда то.

Comment: Пересобрать Linux тебе не нужно, используй лиункс производителя устройства. Но вот initrd по этой книжке собери

Comment: как же эти маркетологи-то головы позабивали всем вокруг. программа linux и так работала и работает на вашем смартфоне. и до начала ваших манипуляций и после. всё та же самая программа linux, а другую программу в качестве ядра операционной системы вы вряд ли сможете запустить.

Comment: Филин энтузиаст 

Comment: 2 GB оперативки маловато для современных браузеров. Среди обычных linux-приложений мне не известно приложений для совершения звонков через аппарат. Графические программы обычно ориентированы на мышь и клавиатуру и без них какие-то функции будет просто невозможно вызвать тапая по экрану.

Comment: Извините , немного ошибся ... Это свободной оперативки было 2 GB , а встроенной 4 GB ...

Comment: А насчёт тапов , это всё надо будет подключать с помощью драйверов ...